# Default styles for Chrome autofill dropdown

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Does anybody know how to set default styles for Chrome native dropdown? Better without reset the browser

At the moment I have a black background for the dropdown and I'm trying to return default values.

[image]

I've searched about changing styles for native dropdown and all answers was "No, you cant change native styles", but it's happend somehow.

I tried set ***webkit-autofill*** styles, but only input changes

*Chrome Version 79.0.3945.130 (Official Build) (64-bit)*
*Ubuntu 18.04*

Comment: Not sure if it will help but there is another html5 pseudo selector for auto filled inputs that's is :valid see if you can select through it and override styles for auto filled.

Comment: Unfortunatelly doesn't work